# PHP How to get data from all column from csv file and store it in array

Tags: php

I am trying to read each column from the third one to the 12th from a csv file and store all the data in an array. At this point I only get the last column: Here is my file:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$in_file = 'gabriel-images-urls.csv';

$fd = fopen($in_file, "r");

$new_array[]= array();

$start_row = 2;

$i = 2;//define row count flag


while (($row = fgetcsv($fd)) !== FALSE) {
    for ($col=3; $col<=11; $col++) {         
        $row[] = $row[$col];
        if($i >= $start_row){
           $url = $row[$col];
           $url_name = basename($url);
           $new_array[] = [$row[0], $row[1],$url_name];
      }
   $i++;
 }
?>
```

So the idea is the variable $url_name to contain all the links from the above file with their basename and if it is posssible to be seperated with a comma in the array. Expected output:

```
     Array

    (
        [0] => G5651407J
        [1] => G5651407J
        [2] => https://assets.suredone.com/683987/media-photos/g5651407j-gabriel-g56514-front-right-ultra-premium-twin-tube-strut-for-lexus-toyota-models.jpg, https://assets.suredone.com/683987/media-photos/cfc869-bendix-premium-copper-cfc869-front-brake-pad-set-for-chrysler-sebring-models-2.jpeg, https://assets.suredone.com/683987/media-photos/cfc869-bendix-premium-copper-cfc869-front-brake-pad-set-for-chrysler-sebring-models-3.jpeg
    )
```

I want all of the links to be at the third element of the array, seperated with the comma.

Comment: please add your expected output !

Comment: I added it in the post!

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug the given code? Small hint: are you sure you want to append everything to `$new_array` within that `for` loop? That might end in eight new elements per CSV line

Comment: Additionally, is that single array element the whole result for the given input? If yes, what's the rule behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$in_file = 'gabriel-images-urls.csv';
$fd = fopen($in_file, "r");
$new_array= array();
$i=0;
while (($row = fgetcsv($fd)) !== FALSE)
{
    if($i!=0)
    {
        $url_array = array();
        for ($col=2; $col<=11; $col++) 
        {
            if(isset($row[$col]) && trim($row[$col])!=null)
            {
                $url = $row[$col];
                $url_array[] =$url;
            }

        }

        $new_array[] = array($row[0],$row[1],implode($url_array,','));
    }
    else if($i==0)
    {
        $i++;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I have also optimized your code to stop incrementing row flag every time. Check if it works fine for you.

Comment: Actually for the third element I only get commas, not the actual links.

Comment: can you share your csv

Comment: It is shared in the post.

Comment: [0] => 142386
            [1] => 142386
            [2] => ,,,,,,,,

Comment: This is my result.

Comment: Try again. I have made some changes

Comment: No it still prints the commas as the third element.

Comment: Your CSV is not clear. If I could have your csv, it could have been better

Comment: I can send it to you, the above example was only a part of it, but only these rows have the multiple data.

Comment: plz share csv . It would be help

Comment: <a href=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mZTImYN-Z0h56KP3mr4gMQi6WUyZeJui/view?usp=sharing>file</a> This is the link to download the file.

Comment: Try now, I have removed the empty rows